# Counting Substrings from a List, inside a String

Tags: python, string, list, counter

I want to have a list of substrings look for inside of a string, and to receive the count of however many times a substring appears in that string.

```
list = ['one', 'two', 'three']
str = "one one two four five six"
count = str.count(list)
```

So in this example, count should be 3. However, .count() can't read strings from a list for some reason, so I'm not sure how to work around that.

Comment: That's not a tuple, that's a list...

Comment: 2 of the 3 answers down there are based on the assumption that the input strings will always be complete words. So I have to ask: What would the expected output of `tup = ['foo']` and `str = 'foobar'` be? 0 or 1?

Comment: Ah, you're right, my bad. I'll fix that.

Comment: Related: [Count occurrences of a couple of specific words](//stackoverflow.com/q/9498665)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use `sum` with a generator expression and utilizing `set` for O(1) lookup. `str.split()` splits your string into a list, separating by whitespace.

```
str_set = {'one', 'two', 'three'}
x = 'one one two four five six'

count = sum(i in str_set for i in x.split())

print(count)  # 3
```

The reason this works is `bool` is a subclass of `int`, so we can sum `True` elements as if they are integers.

Note you have a list and string, no tuple involved. In addition, do not name variables after classes (e.g. `list`, `str`, `set`).

Comment: This is definitely the most performant answer but could be harder to understand for beginners. Not to say this isn't the best way here... it is.

Comment: This one seems to have the intended result, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is the following

```
count = sum([str.count(e) for e in tup))
```

Which `sums` the number of times any `substring` in the `tup` appears in `str`.

Also, your `tuple` is a `list`. To make it a `tuple` (immutable), use `(`

```
('one', 'two', 'three')
```

Also, you should use the variable name `str_` (standard python convention) to avoid overloading the `str` object.

Answer (score 0):

Use a generator expression and `sum`:

```
count = sum(1 for x in the_string.split(" ") if x in tup)
```